# How to check if a sequence of moves in Tic-Tac-Toe is valid

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string "x-xoxoo--" which represents a stage in a game Tic-Tac-Toe

```
x|-|x
o|x|o
o|-|-
```

I know how to check if one stage in a list is valid:

```py
from math import *

def check(play):
    x = 0
    o = 0
    for item in play:
        if item == "x":
            x = x+1
        if item == "o":
            o = o+1
    return fabs(x-o) <= 1
```

I want to check if for example the list `["x-xoxoo--", "x-xoxoox-",  "x-xoxooxo"]` describes a possible sequence of consecutive moves in the game.

for example:

`["----x----", "o---x----", "oo--x----"]`  is not valid

and another

`["----xo---", "o---xo---", "x---xo---"]`  is not valid

I also know how to count differences between two sequences:

```py
    def difference(seq1, seq2):
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(seq1)):
            if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
                count += 1
        return count
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: In game I have to check all possible stages

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: You should generalise: at what _point_ in the game does a "satge" become invalid? You need to consider a _sequence_ of stages because, say, `x---xo---` by itself is fine: X made a move, O made a move, X made a move again. But `x---xo---` _after_ `o---xo---` (or vice versa) is not valid. Also, if O makes the first move, `o---x----` followed by `oo--x----` is perfectly fine. So, you can't check "if that _one_ element in a list is valid" without considering its neighbours, possibly including the very first stage.

Answer (score 1):

Most problems like this are made easy or difficult by what data structure you use to represent the inputs. My solution is to represent a position as a set of tuples like `{(0, 'x'), (4, 'o')}`, where the first component of the tuple is the index of the board position, and the second is the symbol of the player.

My choice of this data structure is motivated by the simplicity of testing whether two board positions differ by one move, and testing whether the game has been won.

I'm going to assume that the sequence must be a whole game starting from an empty board, and that `'x'` always plays first.

---

Converting a string to a set of these tuples is easy using a set comprehension with `enumerate`:

```py
def string_to_position(board):
    return { (i, s) for i, s in enumerate(board) if s in 'xo' }
```

The next step is to test whether a board position `q` can be made from position `p` by one extra move of player `s`. For this to be true,

- `p` must be a subset of `q`,
- The set `q - p` must have a single element,
- That single element must be a move by player `s`.

The simplicity of testing this using sets is one motivation for my choice of data structure.

```py
def one_more_move(p, q, s):
    if p <= q:
        diff = q - p
        return len(diff) == 1 and list(diff)[0][1] == s
    else:
        return False
```

A sequence of legal moves in Tic-Tac-Toe cannot continue after one player has won, so we need to test whether a board position is a win.

That is, for each winning line for each player, we need to test whether that line exists on the board. To do this using sets, we can just test whether each "win" is a subset of the board position. The only hard part is listing all of the "wins"; there are 8 three-in-a-rows, but we need each for both players:

```py
all_lines = [
    # horizontal
    (0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8),
    # vertical
    (0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8),
    # diagonal
    (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6),
]
all_wins = [
    { (i, s) for i in line }
    for s in 'xo'
    for line in all_lines
]

def is_win(p):
    return any( win <= p for win in all_wins )
```

Now we're ready to write a function to test whether a sequence of positions is a valid game of Tic-Tac-Toe:

```py
import itertools

def is_valid_game(positions):
    # first, convert to our data structure
    positions = [ string_to_position(p) for p in positions ]

    # the game starts with an empty board
    p = set()
    won_already = False

    # cycle between players x, o, x, o...
    for q, s in zip(positions, itertools.cycle('xo')):
        if won_already or not one_more_move(p, q, s):
            return False

        won_already = is_win(q)
        p = q

    # if we saw every position and didn't find any problem, then the
    # sequence of positions must be a valid game of Tic-Tac-Toe
    return True
```

Tests:

```py
>>> is_valid_game(['----x----', 'o---x----', 'ox--x----'])
True
>>> is_valid_game(['----x----', 'o---x----', 'oo--x----'])
False # o is not allowed to play twice in a row
>>> is_valid_game(['----x----', '----o----'])
False # o is not allowed to play where x played
>>> is_valid_game(['o--------'])
False # o is not allowed to play first
>>> is_valid_game(['----x-x--'])
False # x can't start by making two moves
>>> is_valid_game(['----x----', 'o---x----', 'o--xx----', 'oo-xx----', 'oo-xxx---'])
True
>>> is_valid_game(['----x----', 'o---x----', 'o--xx----', 'oo-xx----', 'oo-xxx---', 'oooxxx---'])
False # can't keep playing after x wins
```

Comment: This isn't quite what he wants, he can get a sequence of moves at any point in the game.

Comment: I'm aware of the slight difference; since it's likely a learning exercise for the OP, I chose to write an answer that demonstrates the approach I would take. My solution can be adapted to the OP's needs but not in an entirely trivial way; there will be a need, given the first board position in the list, to determine which player is next to play.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your function for checking if a single position is valid can be simpler:

```py
def check(position):
    # there should either be the same number of "x"s as "o"s or one more "x"
    return (position.count("x") - position.count("o")) in (0, 1)
```

To determine whether a sequence of moves is valid, we need to check that the first move is valid, then determine who's move it is

```py
def to_move(position):
    if (position.count("x") - position.count("o")) == 0:
        return "x"
    return "o"
```

then iterate over each position with the one that came before (we do this with `zip(some_list, some_list[1:])`), generating all the possible moves from the previous position (there can be at most 9)

```py
def generate_all_moves(position):
    moves = []
    for index, piece in enumerate(position):
        if piece == "-":
            # strings are immutable so we need to convert it to a list
            new_move = list(position)
            new_move[index] = to_move(position)
            # and convert it back to a sting
            moves.append(''.join(new_move))
    return moves
```

and checking if the current position is one of them.

```py
def check_moves(positions):
    if not check(position[0]):
        return False
    for prev_position, current_position in zip(positions, positions[1:]):
        if current_position not in generate_all_moves(prev_position):
            return False
    return True
```

This works for any number of moves except 0 (which should return `True`), not just 3.

You can't make moves after a game has been won so you should also write a function that checks if a game is won, and if it's won in any move but the last one, return `False`.

It might be a bit cleaner to generate the entire game tree upfront (should take a trivial amount of ram, like a few MB) as a dictionary of position -> list of valid moves and then just looking up each position in it.